# Thread target function isn't finishing

Tags: python, multithreading, function, speech-to-text, pyttsx

I have a thread being created at a certain point in a loop, but it won't create the thread again because the thread's target hasn't completed. I'm using pyttsx3 to do speech to text in the following function:

```
def speak(sentence):
    speech_engine.say(sentence)
    speech_engine.runAndWait()
    print('Done')
```

The print at the bottom is never run even though the engine is done speaking.
Here is where I'm creating the thread:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=speak, args=(res,))
t1.start()
```

Does anyone know why the function isn't completing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, a previously created thread not ending shouldn't prevent the creation of another thread (unless you ran out of memory or hit a thread limit imposed by the OS). Secondly, this would certainly be because of `speech_engine.runAndWait()`. Have you read the docs for it to see if it mentions why it may hang?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I couldn't find anything in the documentation about it other than this:

Comment: runAndWait() → None
Blocks while processing all currently queued commands. Invokes callbacks for engine notifications appropriately. Returns when all commands queued before this call are emptied from the queue.

Comment: It could be that you're creating threads faster than `.say` can finish. I've never used that library before, but if `.say` is queuing "commands", and you're queuing new commands faster than they can finish, `speech_engine.runAndWait()` may never return. You said you're creating the threads in a loop? Try adding a `time.sleep` delay in the thread-creation loop. Also, showing a [mcve] here might make the problem clearer.

Comment: .say sets the speech and run and wait says the sentence but the sentence is done before I use .say again, but for some reason I can't figure out, runandwait never actually completes even though the sentence is done. @Carcigenicate